# apportable: iOS 7.1 is MKMapItem supported

Tags: android, ios, apportable, mkmapitem

apportable reports the following error:

> error: unknown type name 'MKMapItem'; did you mean 'MKMapView'?

```
MKMapItem* destination =  [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placeMark];
```

Does Apportable support MKMapItem?

Comment: Could you give more information on what is causing this error?

Comment: My app compiles and works perfectly inxcode 5 and  iOS 7.1 and the app is currently shipping in the app store. I now want to port to android and so using apportable out of the box I get the error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, MapKit isn't yet supported by apportable. you can make an effort yourself using bridgekit to use the native android mapping APIs, documented here: http://docs.apportable.com/using-java.html